# how to show full text over the svg height?

Tags: html, css, svg

how to show full text in the svg , after rotation its showing partially,
how to show the text over the height of the svg control.

```html
  <svg  width="100" viewBox="-3 0 68 196">
      <text x="90" y="0" fill="red" transform="rotate(90)">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</text> 
      <text x="90" y="-50" fill="red" transform="rotate(90)">United States of America</text>    
</svg>
```

Comment: Do you want that text appear smaller? That it continues on the next line? Please explain the expected output.

Comment: i don want the text appear smaller. i want the full text shown  vertically, the svg height is blocking the text , how to overcome that issue ?

Comment: @enxaneta  Changed it with viewbox, but its still not working , the text will start at the bottom of the viewbox.

Comment: Change the viewBox y and height values till they work for you.

Comment: @enxaneta changed as you told , but not working

Comment: Try  viewBox="-3 **90** 68 196" since x="90" should not changed

Answer (score 1):

After setting your text `x` value to `0` its seems good to me.

```html
<svg  width="100" viewBox="-3 0 68 196">
  <text x="0" y="0" fill="red" transform="rotate(90)">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</text> 
  <text x="0" y="-50" fill="red" transform="rotate(90)">United States of America</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: x value should not changed in the existing code , i have to number over the names .

Comment: Your `x` value is basically moving the text out of the boundry

Comment: can it be shown over the boundary?

Answer (score 0):

Change the y-coordinate of the viewbox attribute as needed:

```html
<svg  width="100" viewBox="-3 90 68 196">
  <text x="90" y="0" fill="red" transform="rotate(90)">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</text> 
  <text x="90" y="-50" fill="red" transform="rotate(90)">United States of America</text>      
</svg>
```

Comment: the height for the svg is fixed, i cannot change it.